# Why WEKA considers data as attributes?

Tags: machine-learning, nlp, weka, text-classification

I am trying to predict a category of given string. Below is the sample of arff file i have(REDACTED)

```
@ATTRIBUTE Text string
@ATTRIBUTE class {type1,type2,type3}
@DATA
"Data for type1" type1
"Data for type2" type2
"Data for type3" type3
"Data for type3" type3 
"Data for type1" type1 
"Data for type2" type2
```

I believe the attributes in the above set are Text and Class. However the program recognises each and every work in the Data as attribute. Is this expected?

```
Enumeration<Attribute> attributeEnumeration =   dataset.enumerateAttributes();
while(attributeEnumeration.hasMoreElements()){
            Attribute attribute = attributeEnumeration.nextElement();
            LOGGER.info("attr name"+attribute.name());

        }
```

I am following the weka docs along with

https://www.codingame.com/playgrounds/6734/machine-learning-with-java---part-5-naive-bayes
https://github.com/nsadawi/WEKA-API/tree/master/src

Thanks, 
Jai

Comment: Just a guess: is "Text" a reserved word? Try changing this to something else in line 1 of your arff file.

Comment: @zbicyclist tried, no luck.